# pyspark RandomForestClassifier not recognizing weightCol paramter

Tags: python, pyspark, random-forest, apache-spark-ml

I'm trying to implement a weighted random forest model on some imbalanced dataset.

Here is what I am trying to do: I have a Jupyter notebook running in Google Colab, running a Spark cluster.

First I install:

```
!apt-get update -qq > /dev/null
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
!wget -q https://downloads.apache.org/spark/spark-2.4.8/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
!tar xf spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
!pip install -q findspark
```

Then set up the Spark context:

```
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7"

import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
import numpy as np 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession #to make dataframe from rdd easily
import time

sc = SparkContext(appName="bitcoinFraud", master="local[*]")
spark_session = SparkSession(sc)
```

Finally, after making some DataFrames and whatnot, I try to instantiate a random forest model which will digest training data, including a column of instance weights:

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier

# define the random forest model, using weights this time
rf_weighted = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="indexedLabel", featuresCol="indexedFeatures", weightCol='weight', numTrees=100)
```

However, I get this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'weightCol'
```

I was surprised, because the [documentation for RandomForestClassifier](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier.html#pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier.weightCol) seems to say that there is such an argument. Furthermore, [this source](https://www.datatrigger.org/post/spark_3_weighted_random_forest/) seems to show it working.

I have no idea what's going on--I'm new to Spark, and I really need some help!

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available in Spark < 3.xx--it's enough to download the most recent version of Spark to fix this problem.